# Let N∞ be the set of all infinite sequences of nonnegative integers. Is it uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$N^{∞}$, which is the set of all infinite sequences uncountable?

I thought of using Cantor's theorem to prove that it is uncountable but I'm not sure if i can apply it here.

Comment: This is a great test of your understanding of Cantor's result: can you produce a similar argument here? That is, suppose $F:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^\infty$ is some map; do you see how to use a diagonal-y idea to produce a sequence $s\in\mathbb{N}^\infty\setminus ran(F)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Show that the subset $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} := \big\{ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}: x_n \in \{0,1\} \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\big\} \subset \mathbb{N}^{\infty}$ it is uncountable.

**Hint 2:**

> Use a diagonalization argument.